# Basis and dimension of a kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $E$ be the vector space of functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which are $C^{\infty}$ and $u$ the endomorphism such that $u(f)=f'-af$. Find the dimension and the basis of $\ker u^n$. I guess that its dimension is $n$ but I don't know where to start. Do you have an idea?

Edit : $u^n$ is $u$ composed itself $n$ times.

Comment: Where to start: you could consider the case $n=1$. Once you solved that problem, try to find an explicit formula for $u^2$ and solve that problem. Then do $u^3$. After a while make an educated conjecture. Then try to write a proof.

Comment: I did it for $n=1,2$ but I don't know how to solve linear differential equations of order 3... There must be a faster way since we "only" need a basis and the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Show by induction that

$$ u^n(f) = \sum_{k=0}^n { n \choose k } f^{(k)}(-a)^{n-k}. $$

Hence, the equation $u^n(f) = 0$ is a linear homogeneous differential equation of order $n$ with constant coefficients so it has $n$ linearly independent solutions. The characteristic equation for the ODE is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n { n \choose k } x^k (-a)^{n-k} = (x - a)^n $$

for which $x = a$ is a root of order $n$. Hence, a basis for the solution space is given by

$$ e^{ax}, xe^{ax}, \dots, x^{n-1}e^{ax}. $$